# tkinter window get x, y, geometry/coordinates without top of window

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am using tk in python (3), though I'd assume that this applies to any language. I am looking to get the current x, y coordinates of a tk window outside of the title bar:

```
import tkinter  
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

however, using `root.winfo_y()` gives me the coordinates including the depth of the titlebar. For a window that is in the upper left corner of my screen:

```
root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y()          # returns (0, 22)
```

In other words, running:

```
root.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y()))
```

will move down the window by 22 pixels (the height of the title bar) every time I call it. How can I get the actual coordinates of the entire window?

Comment: I'm not sure, but winfo_rootx() and winfo_rooty() might be what you are looking for.

Comment: yeah i tried those, same effect :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Tkinter, most configuration functions when used without new value arguments returns the current value(s). Thus `root.geometry()` (plus a few string parsing) can serve your goal.

Comment: yep this is what I was looking for! As a side note, `root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y()` i think normally should return the same coordinates as `root.geometry()`, however, the problem I am having is that i use 2 monitors, running OSX, and the one on the right is my 'home' monitor with the file bar that sits at the very top of the screen. Using `root.geometry()` solves my issues, though, thanks!

Comment: It still works, thanks :-) I got expected values with this code:
x,y = (int(s) for s in self.geometry().split("+")[1:])