# Tkinter canvas and pyinstaller - Resolution problem

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have created an app with Tkinter. The app contains a figure in a `FigureCanvasTkAgg()`.

I created an .exe file using `pyinstaller`. The app itself is displayed properly (that is, as when it is run from Spyder) without resolution problem. The figure in the canvas, however, has all its text too large (the legend ends up outside the canvas, which is not the case when running it from Spyder).

**View of the canvas:** The legend at the bottom is cut by the outside of the canvas (grey area.
[image]

I tried to:

1. Reduce the font size in the figure from the app code. This does not work.
2. Set the process dpi awareness (Windows, `SetProcessDpiAwareness`) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62981506). This does not work.

Does someone has a suggestion?